# problem with lists?

Tags: python

```
j=0
x=[]
for j in range(9):
  x=x+ [j]
```

this will output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

i wanted it as

```
['1','2','3'...
```

how can I get it?

Comment: It should output `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the "good" python ways are already posted, but I want to show you how you would modify your example to make it work the way you want it:

```
j=0  
x=[]  
for j in range(9):  
   x = x + [str(j)]
```

Comment: Rule of Clarity: Clarity is better than cleverness.

Comment: I might argue that `x.append(str(j))` is more clear than the `+` operator.

Answer (score 12):

convert to string:

```
>>> [str(i) for i in range(9)]
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

if you want your list to start with `1` just change your `range` function:

```
>>> [str(i) for i in range(1, 9)]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Also, you don't need to initialise loop variable (`j=0` is not required).

Answer (score 4):

Python 2

```
>>> map(str, range(1, 9))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Python 3

```
>>> list(map(str, range(1, 9)))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Documentation for `range`:

- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range

Comment: Note that, on Py3k this will return lazily as `<map object at 0x????>`. One needs to evaluate to a list with `list(map(str, range(9)))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
j=0
x=[]
for j in range(9):
    x=x+[str(j)]
```